# charAt(0) Returning an Unknown Source Error

Tags: char, range, charat

I've already looked in this thread:
[StringIndexOutOfBoundsException String index out of range: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690995/stringindexoutofboundsexception-string-index-out-of-range-0)
But checking the length did not fix the issue. I'll just post my entire program here, it's not long yet. I cannot think of what the problem is...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Project2_Mazzone {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

String gender;
double drinks, weight, hours, age, alcMetabolized, ratio, limit;
char letter;

System.out.println("Welcome to the BAC calculator!");
System.out.println();

//Gathering info from the drinker & setting values accordingly
System.out.print("How many drinks have you had? ");
    drinks = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.print("How much do you weigh (in pounds)? ");
    weight = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.print("How many hours ago did you start drinking? ");
    hours = scan.nextDouble();
    alcMetabolized = .015 * hours;      //Stores value for alcohol metabolized
System.out.print("Are you a male or a female? ");
    gender = scan.nextLine();
    letter = gender.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    if(letter == 'M'){      //Stores value for ratio based on gender
        ratio = .66;
    }else{
        ratio = .73;
    }
```

It's showing me this error before I even press anything on that line:
http://gyazo.com/60f1cd4fe4e0718c0c8264bfd4049be3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to read gender

```
scan.next();
```

scan.nextLine() will try to returns the rest of the current line and in your case it will be empty. You can only use this method if you are planning to read all the line in its entirety from the beginning.