# Hive String index out of range error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to execute this below query in Hive(cloudera),

```
select a.col1,a.col2
FROM t1 a LEFT SEMI JOIN (select * from t2 where y = 0) b on (a.col1 =b.x);
```

Below is the error I am getting,

```
Your query has the following error(s):

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException String index out of range: 0
```

I am getting this even if i run just `select * from t2 where y = 0`. But the same query is working fine in Impala. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException String index out of range: 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690995/stringindexoutofboundsexception-string-index-out-of-range-0)

Comment: The same thing is happening to me and it is very annoying. As a workaround, copy your query and open a new editor. Your query should work now there.

Answer (score 0):

The might have failed because there is an empty `as` in select